# Wix Error message 2343

Tags: xml, wix, installation

In Windows Installer XML (WIX) My code compiles OK but after you accept the licence Agreement, you get the following error message: "The installer has encoutered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2343. I tried to make the desktop shortcut optional after succeeding with creating one, but after deciding against it, I tried to undo the changes and got the error. My code is as follows, and since I don't know where the problem is, I can't single out a code snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MemberManagement" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="RFIdentity LLC" UpgradeCode="d525ca33-b610-43f8-8f02-22b5da56c72c">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MemberManagement" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Files" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_InboxDir" />
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_PicturesDir"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_EmployeesDir"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_MembersDir" />
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_00385TXT" />
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_10104TXT" />
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_AForgeDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_AForgeXML"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_AForge.VideoDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_AForge.VideoXML"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_AForge.Video.DirectShowDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_AForge.Video.DirectShowXML"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_AlienRFID2DLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_ConfigXML"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_ConfigRFIdentityCommXML"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_DashboardXML"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_GAO236004ReaderDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_MemberManagementEXE"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_Microsoft.ReportViewer.CommonDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModelDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinFormsDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_Microsoft.SqlServer.TypesDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_Newtonsoft.JsonDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_NodaTimeDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_System.Net.Http.FormattingDLL"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_OutboxDir"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_GhostePNG"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CMP_GhostmPNG"/>
    </Feature>
    <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallValidate"
                  AllowDowngrades="no"
                  DowngradeErrorMessage="You Cannot Downgrade"/>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">



      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"
                 Name="Desktop">
        <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop"
                   Guid="*">
          <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut"
                    Name="RF Identity MMS"
                    Description="MemberManagement"
                    Target="[MEMBERMANAGEMENTDIRPROPERTY]MemberManagement.exe"
                    WorkingDirectory="MEMBERMANAGEMENTDIRPROPERTY" />
          <RemoveFolder Id="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall"/>
          <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                         Key="C:\Program Files (x86)\Member Management\MemberManagement.exe"
                         Name="installed"
                         Type="integer"
                         Value="1"
                         KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
          <Directory Id="InboxDir"
                     Name="Inbox" />
          <Directory Id="OutboxDir"
                     Name="Outbox" />
          <Directory Id="PicturesDir"
                     Name="Pictures">
            <Directory Id="EmployeesDir"
                       Name="Employees">
              <Component Id="CMP_GhostePNG"
     Guid="7E5F6F79-52AC-4B8C-837D-A04AD4B5115B">
                <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_Pictures_MembersPNG"
                      Source="Ghost.png"
                      KeyPath="yes" />
              </Component>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="MembersDir"
                       Name="Members">
              <Component Id="CMP_GhostmPNG"
     Guid="3DA40D25-F724-4572-B529-45DE9B155687">
                <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_Pictures_EmployeesPNG"
                      Source="Ghost.png"
                      KeyPath="yes" />
              </Component>
            </Directory>
          </Directory>


        </Directory>

      <Directory Id="RFIdentity" Name="RFIdentity LLC">


        <Directory Id="MEMBERMANAGEMENTDIRPROPERTY" Name="MemberManagement">
        </Directory>
 </Directory>
      </Directory>


  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
      <!--Files-->
    <ComponentGroup Id="Files" Directory="TARGETDIR">
      <Component Id="CMP_00385TXT"
                 Guid="DB1B8002-EBE0-40BC-953B-FFD97209FC0A">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_00385TXT"
              Source="00385.txt"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_10104TXT"
                 Guid="1696EAA7-ED90-4527-936D-8122CDA145DD">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_10104TXT"
              Source="10104.txt"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_AForgeDLL"
                 Guid="3F5A2372-639B-4048-A1DF-9AE2D92DB8CE">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_AForgeDLL"
              Source="AForge.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_AForgeXML"
           Guid="2C519B46-9C77-4ABB-8B2D-7912DB1A46AC">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_AForgeXML"
              Source="AForge.xml"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_AForge.VideoDLL"
     Guid="1E571689-51A3-4C8E-A3EB-31E2F49EDAB9">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_AForge.VideoDLL"
              Source="AForge.Video.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_AForge.VideoXML"
     Guid="3881A2B7-EE13-4814-8370-0B51803ABB2C">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement.AForge.VideoXML"
              Source="AForge.Video.xml"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_AForge.Video.DirectShowDLL"
     Guid="B7865DCF-12EC-40DF-B7CE-FCBED97DE12A">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_AForge.Video.DirectShowDLL"
              Source="AForge.Video.DirectShow.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_AForge.Video.DirectShowXML"
     Guid="09E0A00E-CB2F-40A1-9AF6-A9EDF5B7C10D">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_AForge.Video.DirectShowXML"
              Source="AForge.Video.DirectShow.xml"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_AlienRFID2DLL"
     Guid="FBB8FE0C-C403-42C3-A279-A87319DA7A1C">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_AlienRFID2DLL"
              Source="AlienRFID2.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_ConfigXML"
     Guid="E078DA58-EAF0-4B93-BBE3-9CCFE136B10E">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_ConfigXML"
              Source="Config.xml"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_ConfigRFIdentityCommXML"
     Guid="0AC563E1-145B-4972-AA4D-4BF54D5C1D9A">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_ConfigRFIdentityCommXML"
              Source="ConfigRFIdentityComm.xml"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_DashboardXML"
     Guid="D5A375AA-2578-4C5C-8D95-83DBDA8363BA">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_DashboardXML"
              Source="Dashboard.xml"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_GAO236004ReaderDLL"
     Guid="91AAE974-DF3B-4410-9199-1961891ED0AD">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_GAO236004ReaderDLL"
              Source="GAO236004Reader.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_MemberManagementEXE"
     Guid="0E5AEA14-4692-49CD-971A-7A5A7475ECD3">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_MemberManagementEXE"
              Source="MemberManagement.exe"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_Microsoft.ReportViewer.CommonDLL"
     Guid="17CE9ABB-1CC0-4939-998B-0C41F31477A2">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement.Microsoft.ReportViewer.CommonDLL"
              Source="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModelDLL"
     Guid="02E729E4-F7DE-42CB-B192-6A4EF0F7438B">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModelDLL"
              Source="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinFormsDLL"
     Guid="ECDB56C5-0CF9-4574-941F-417B08C68C98">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinFormsDLL"
              Source="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_Microsoft.SqlServer.TypesDLL"
     Guid="BD62B42E-05FA-4B19-AE38-59DC52DA60B5">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement.Microsoft.SqlServer.TypesDLL"
              Source="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_Newtonsoft.JsonDLL"
     Guid="CACC1E96-EC82-4946-A2F0-592A7EB236ED">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement.Newtonsoft.JsonDLL"
              Source="Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_NodaTimeDLL"
     Guid="BC333575-BEA8-4D0F-BF69-50907BAF8273">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_NodaTimeDLL"
              Source="NodaTime.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CMP_System.Net.Http.FormattingDLL"
     Guid="386D83B7-62D7-4F7B-8FFD-C7D1395C1FBD">
        <File Id="FILE_MemberManagement_System.Net.Http.FormattingDLL"
              Source="System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"
              KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
    <!--Folders-->
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

    <DirectoryRef Id="InboxDir">
      <Component Id="CMP_InboxDir"
                 Guid="65052C92-432D-4DA9-A7E9-8DABD5E4BF84"
                 KeyPath="yes">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="OutboxDir">
      <Component Id="CMP_OutboxDir"
                 Guid="F1589519-FF2A-40D3-A218-5A414EF44EDD"
                 KeyPath="yes">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="PicturesDir">
      <Component Id="CMP_PicturesDir"
                 Guid="B43CA519-8037-402B-A6EE-AA69C0ECE47A"
                 KeyPath="yes">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="EmployeesDir">
      <Component Id="CMP_EmployeesDir"
                 Guid="D6D4916B-B657-478B-B01A-0CF9B7485809"
                 KeyPath="yes">
        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="MembersDir">
      <Component Id="CMP_MembersDir"
                 Guid="85BD631F-0CD0-4B2A-B846-AC7929FA1751"
                 KeyPath="yes">

        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR"
          Value="MemberManagementFolder" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="banner.bmp"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="InstallBackground.bmp"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILiscenseRtf" Value="LiscenceAgreement.rtf"/>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```